# Wpf binding custom class with list to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new in WPF, and trying to work with binding. Now I'm binding a list of custom object to `ListBox` like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my C# code:

```
public List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();

public MainWindow()
{
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "111" });
    lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "222" });
    lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "333" });
    lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "444" });
    lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "555" });     

    this.DataContext = lst;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And also XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="139" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,102,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

That's work fine but I want to bind a class that contains List as field, so my C# code looks like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    private List<Foo> lst;

    public List<Foo> Lst
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Bar()
    {
        lst = new List<Foo>();
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "111" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "222" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "333" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "444" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "555" });            
    }
}
```

And also

```
Bar bar=new Bar();
this.DataContext=bar;
```

When I doing so, nothing works. So I can't figure out how can I bind `bar.Lst` to `ListBox`. Can anybody explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make little modification to your `Bar` class.

```
public class Bar
{
    private List<Foo> lst;

    public List<Foo> Lst
    {
        get { return lst;}        
    }

    public Bar()
    {
        lst = new List<Foo>();
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "111" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "222" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "333" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "444" });
        lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "555" });            
    }
}
```

And in you Xaml.

```
<ListBox Height="139" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,102,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Lst}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use `Lst` property not `lst` field. it is better using [`AutoProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) And then your `DataContext` like this:`this.DataContext = bar.Lst;` So Change your code in this way:

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<Foo> Lst { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        Lst = new List<Foo>();
        Lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "111" });
        Lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "222" });
        Lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "333" });
        Lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "444" });
        Lst.Add(new Foo { Name = "555" });
    }
}
```

And:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Bar bar = new Bar();
     this.DataContext = bar.Lst;
}
```